# AWS Lambda: How To Remove Environmental Variables from Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that used to use encrypted environmental variables set in the lambda configuration but I no longer need them. I tried removing the env variable in the UI and it no longer shows up but still seeing in the logs:

"Found credentials in environment variables."

I also tried using the update-function-code command without passing an env variable which doesn't work.

Any way to remove the encrypted env variables from my lambda function configuration? I want to ensure unused/unneeded things are removed.

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you see message `"Found credentials in environment variables."` ? Is it something logged by your code?

Comment: It sounds like you have a print statement or something that is printing out this statement.

Comment: Cloudtrail logs and no there is no print statement doing this.

Comment: Could be a caching issue? Your lambdas are reusing enviroments. Try to force a re-init of the environment/vm by e.g. increment/decrement the execution time by a second and save.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried updating function code and configuration via cli but still seeing the logs in cloudtrail. I do have another test function that has an encrypted env variable. Is it possible that The logs are referencing that functions variable even though it is not being executed?

Answer (score 11):

I believe it is a standard output from the inner workings of python lambdas that use boto. None of my python Lambdas have credentials and yet I have the same message in all logs of python lambdas.

Comment: Thanks, Neil. I am also thinking this is standard output as I have scrubbed everything and still getting the log message. I am moving on from this and chalking it up as something Lambda/boto3 does.

Comment: see @jrc's answer below to address the concern.

Answer (score 8):

The log message is coming from the "botocore" logger.

This will effectively suppress that message and others from `boto3`:

```
logging.getLogger("boto3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger("botocore").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: When I tested this, I only needed the second one, that is for botocore.
Also, I used an enviroment variable to set this, in case I needed to see info level notices:


```LOG_VERBOSITY = os.getenv("LOG_VERBOSITY", "WARNING")

logging.getLogger("botocore").setLevel(LOG_VERBOSITY)
```

Comment: or more specific: `logging.getLogger("botocore.credentials").setLevel(logging.WARNING)` see https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1841#issuecomment-1463631944

Answer (score 5):

I know it's a little late to this, but here is my understanding.

The statement "Found credentials in environment variables." does not have anything to do with the environment variables you configured. Apparently, Lambda has a set of reserved environment variables and when your code tries to connect to other AWS services (like S3, SNS etc), Lambda tries to read the credentials from reserved environment variables to make a connection to the other service and in the process logs the statement about where it found the credentials to "stdout"

According to this [article](https://operatingops.org/2019/02/20/simple-python-boto3-logging/), when you have a logger configured with INFO level, then all the .info() statements by your code and the AWS SDK will be logged to "stdout" and thereby ending up in CloudWatch logs. Try setting the logger level to WARNING and observe the logs.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't specify if Python or boto3 is being used but an observation I have is if you are creating a `client` in your lambda script like this:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
```

I believe this is the moment when the logging happens.

If you were to define actual credentials:

```
access_key = os.getenv('ACCESS_KEY')
secret_key = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
```

It doesn't need to "find" them in the environment.